# How to control multiple windows with different PID but from the same program via pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

I want to control multiple accounts of a stock trading software via pywinauto.
For example, I open the software twice for two different accounts, then 2 tab windows appear with different PID.
My question is how to control these 2 tab windows individually via pywinauto?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you create Application object, it binds window search to the app PID automatically. Just create and `.start()` two Application objects. Or do you want to connect to existing windows? The more detailed question -> the more detailed answer. ;)

Comment: My reputation is not enough that I can't attached screen snapshots to give more details of my questions.
Yes, I want to connect to existing windows. 
As they have the same window titles and I don't know their PID in advance, I'd like to know how to connect to them individually.

Comment: I used inspect.exe to check the 2 tab windows' information, for example, one's PID = 10692, the other is 10424, class='CCustomTabCtrl', ProviderDescription:[pid:10464,hwnd:0x706CC Main:Nested [pid:10692,hwnd:0x706CC Annotation(parent link) 
It seems they have the main PID=10464.

Comment: If these tabs have common parent window, then you just need `.child_window(...., found_index=0)` in search criteria to get the first tab. My statement about pid binding is true for top level windows only.